# Why is my Android ActionBar scrolling away?

Tags: android, appbar

OK, I have an app that needs access to basic swipe gestures.  I've implemented a `GestureDetector` using code scraped from StackOverflow and then modified (to make it work at all).  For it to work, it needs to steal Touch events.

Originally, I was detecting `onScroll` events and such and trying to pass them on to elements that needed to scroll, but this was really jumpy and never scrolled by the amount I wanted, so I started to simply pass the touch events on to the super-class after reading them.   This caused really strange behavior and some elements never scrolled at all (no idea why), so I started passing events in a 3 way split ... some to the super-class, some to the gesture-detector, and some to the on-screen view that needed to scroll!  Yeah, a mess, but everything is finally working smoothly.  Except ...

If you touch the bottom of an `EditText` (it's full-screen except for the AppBar), then as the keyboard appears and scrolls the `EditText` up, the appbar scrolls off the screen (right under the statusbar icons ... looks weird because they overlay each other) and I can't make it scroll back.  Also means I can't get to my Menu or the Cut/Copy icons.  Hitting the menu key when it has scrolled off crashes the app.

Any idea how to stop the AppBar from scrolling off the screen?

```
 @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    int top = dm.heightPixels - myEditText.getMeasuredHeight();
    MotionEvent mod = MotionEvent.obtain(me.getDownTime(), me.getEventTime(),
            me.getAction(), me.getX(), me.getY()-top, me.getMetaState());

    if (me.getY() <= top)
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    myEditText.onTouchEvent(mod);
    return this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);

}
```

Comment: Are you using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`?

Comment: Can you tell me what that does?   I'm not using it and never heard of it.  The answer below seems to work, but I'm interested in how it differs from adjustPan.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this seems to fix it!  In the activity manifest ...

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Bamn!  No more problems!